# How to set multiple public IPs to GKE Load Balancer via Traefik Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik-ingress

#### Context

I have a single Google Load Balancer in front of my Traefik Ingress controller in GKE cluster.
Load Balancer has a single public IPv4.
That Load Balancer is managed by Traefik Ingress controller.

#### Question

I'd like to add more IPs to this Load Balancer. Do you know how to do that?

#### Goal

The goal is to expose services using IngressRouteTCP with separated IP. I know how to expose them using single IP.

Comment: read through this https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c

Comment: @Bijendra there is nothing about GKE...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose traffic via multiple IPs, you'll just need to create multiple Services of type LoadBalancer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - targetPort: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service2

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - targetPort: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service3

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - targetPort: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

Now this will just expose Traefik on multiple IPs.  I'm not sure how you plan to create the "matches" for this.  `IngressRouteTCP` only has a few matching options as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought not about how to do it using `IngressRouteTCP`, but more likely how to add more IPs to the Load Balancer.
`IngressRouteTCP` does not know which IP is used. I think that if the Load Balancer would have multiple IPs, then all of these IPs would work for the IngressRouteTCP. But by pointing to some specific IP I will connect it with the service in Kubernetes.
So the main question is "How to set multiple IPs for a single Load Balancer in Google?" And keep in mind that this Load Balancer is managed by Traefik through Service with kind: LoadBalancer.

Comment: You can't assign multiple IPs to the same load balancer.  The second part of my answer was trying to show that they way to do the equivalent is by creating multiple Services pointing to the same backend.  Each Service of type Loadbalancer will get you a separate IP address.

Comment: Multiple Load Balancers = bigger costs.
I've seen that LB has `Frontend` elements. Couldn't I just add the next `Frontend` with a separate IPv4 address?

I'd like to have just more than 1 IPv4 address, e.g. if some external service blocks me, then I can switch to different IP.